# unify database initialization in php file

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm completely new to PHP. I am creating a website.

In several pages, I start my code with :

```
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;";
$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
];
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

   //rest of the php + html code here
```

I would like to unify this code in **one php file** and call $pdo in every page. But I want to do it in a safe way. Can anyone help.

Comment: include the file from outside the public area? use a class? Quite a few ways to do this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i saw that its not safe to make $pdo global.

Comment: I never mentioned global.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner your answers are not very clear. I need to initialize $pdo in one file, include the file and use the variable in another page. How can i do this without making it global? Again i am new to php.

Comment: Not clear how? See the answer below.

Comment: [You basically answered your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071418/unify-database-initialization-in-php-file#comment93041381_53071418): *"[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file"*, as [did I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071418/unify-database-initialization-in-php-file#comment93041300_53071418) earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better using a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for this. This way you avoid opening multiple database connections:

```
<?php

class Database
{
    public static $pdo;

    public static function getPDO()
    {
        if (null === self::$pdo) {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;";
            $options = [
              PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
              PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            ];
            try {
              self::$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $options);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
               die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }

    //protected constructor
    protected function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

Then use

```
require_once('path/to/database.php'); //the file with Database class
$pdo = Database::getPDO();
```

Of course, you need to include this file/class in every page.
Also, isn't a good practice to hardcode your database credentials. Better load from some `.env`, `getenv()` or `.ini` file.

Comment: Uh, I'll take over-engineering for a thousand, Alex. And you still never show how to include. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think in a different way. Including will always open a new connection to database, even if it isn't used. With this solution will only open when calling the `getPDO()` method.

Comment: I appreciate your way of thinking but it may be a little over the top for someone who is just getting started with PHP or is new to OOP.

Comment: @JayBlanchard actually I am new to PHP but not new to OOP. This was what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

Save your connection code in a file. Let's call it db_connect.php. Then, using the proper path add the following to each file needing a database connection:

```
include('path/to/db_connect.php');
```

You may also use `include_once()`, `require()` or `require_once()` depending on what your needs are.